# Semantic Application Development

Tags: semantic-web

hi every body
i was looking for a solution or a methodology to develop a sample 
web site that utilizes a semantic database backe-end
i have used protege in previous steps and i have converted my OWL project to 
mysql database backend successfully.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any such resource. 
In general you will need a server to host your data. If your data is in relational databases you will need server like 
[D2R](http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/d2r-server/)
or RDF server like
[Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame/users/ch01.html)
and 
[Virtouso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/)

These servers will allow accessing RDF data. Then you can use different techniques to embed this data in HTML to present it to user(Google it). There are RDF Browsers available as well.
There is a very good article on this topic [here](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/BuildingSemanticWebApplications) based on [this publication](http://www.knublauch.com/publications/MDSW2004.pdf).